# Is it possible to integrate this using regular methods?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Is it possible to do this integral $$ \int \sqrt{(\cos t - t \sin t)^2 + (1 - 5 \cos t)^2} dt$$ by hand using usual methods?
I tried in Wolfram Alpha but it's showing "**SlowLarge** + *constant*".

**Edit :** I was asked to find the arc length of the portion of the curve given by the parametric equation :
$$ x = t \cos t, \\ y = t - 5\sin t$$ and there was a graph attached to the question where I could see that the portion was lying between $x= -π$ and $x = π$.

In the question it was mentioned that "set up an integral. Then use a calculator to fing the length correct upto 4 decimals". But I was confused that whether it was telling me to integrate it entirely using calculator or just to use the calculator while putting values of the limits of $t$.

I set up the integral as $$ \int_{-π}^{π} \sqrt{(\cos t - t \sin t)^2 + (1 - 5 \cos t)^2} dt$$.

But I later realised that I mistakenly put the limits of $x$ in place of $t$. Someone in the comment also said that the limits of $t$ is also $-π$ to $π$. How can I evaluate this(the limits of $t$ from the limits of $x$ I mean), can anyone please help me?

**Edit 2 :**
The original question :
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131451/discussion-on-question-by-itachi-is-it-possible-to-integrate-this-using-regular).

Answer (score 1):

Very often, finding indefinite integral then applying the fundamental theorem of calculus is very different from calculating directly the definite integrals. In a computer, the latter is done by numerical integration while the formal requires symbolic calculation.

> Set up an integral. Then use a calculator to find the length correct up to 4 decimals"

The integral you set up is correct since you calculated the derivatives and applied the length formula correctly.

If you use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com), you can find:

[image]

Comment: How can I see that the limits of $t$ in the integral is also $-π$ to $π$? I've only given the parametric equation and the portion of the graph lying between $x= -π$ and $x=π$. Please answer this one, I've been really confused about it.

Comment: @Itachi: in your previous [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306201/is-it-possible-to-integrate-this-using-regular-methods/4306260?noredirect=1#comment8970417_4306201), you said the parametric equations $x=t\cos t, y=t-5\sin t$ are on $[-\pi,\pi]$, didn't you? Can you please copy and paste the exactly original question?

Comment: yes, but I made a mistake, by that I didn't mean $t \in [-π,π]$. I meant $x \in [-π,π]$. You can see that I've mentioned it repeatedly in the later comments and also in the Edit of my question.

Comment: I'll say once more that in the question there was only the parametric equation and the graph of the portion of the curve lying between $x= - π$ and $x= π$. No information for $t$ was given.

Comment: I uploaded an image of the original question.

Comment: @Itachi: thanks. I see. The (image of) curve is the set $\{(x(t),y(t)): a\le t\le b\}$. According to what you posted, you indeed have $-\pi\le t\le \pi$. Since $x(t)=t\cos t$, it happens that $x$ also has the range from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.

Comment: Yes but how can I mathematically justify that for $-\pi\le t\le \pi$, I'm getting the exact graph that is given in the picture? Say I cannot plot is using computer that for $-\pi\le t\le \pi$, what the set $\{(x(t),y(t)): a\le t\le b\}$ looks like. Yes the x component will always be true bcs $x(t)=t\cos t$ and I can prove it from MVT that for $-\pi\le t\le \pi$, $x$ also range from $-π$ to $π$ taking every value in between but how does it guarantee that $y(t)$ won't be different from the graph given? Am I being able to make you understand that what I'm saying?

Comment: Then I'll post it as an another question. Okay I'll upvote it.